# How to define structs as members of structs?

Tags: c++, struct

I'm trying to define a struct with other structs as members of that struct but I'm not sure how this is done. The code I have looks like this so far:

```
typedef struct name
{

    char fname[15];
    char lname[15];

} Name;

typedef struct info
{

    int grade;
    char phone[13];

} Info;

typedef struct mark
{

    int math;
    int sci;
    int eng;

} Mark;

typedef struct student
{

    Name n;
    Info i;
    Mark m;

} Student;

int main()
{

    Student class_list[30] = { };

}
```

Comment: That looks like C, not C++. Which language do you actually use?

Comment: `typedef struct` -- This is not necessary in C++.  Just `struct` is all you need.

Comment: @Timo I use C++ mostly I believe, I think we may use some of both in our coding though. I'm using this code for a grade 12 computer science project I have. Either way, I'm just trying to figure out how to define this.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? What is the problem with the code? Your question doesn't include a question

Comment: Looks to me like you have it . `student` has a `Name`, an `Info`, and a `Mark` and everything compiles. For syntax questions you should start with [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) rather than Stack Overflow. There's going to be stuff you don't quite grok, but it looks like you did get this and a non-fraudulent text would have told you that a lot quicker than typing all that stuff in.

Comment: @bolov yes, I'm wondering how to define the struct 'class_list' at the end of the code, including my structs I have made.

Comment: Ah-ha! I may have misread your intent. You have defined an array of `student`s, but are you asking how to initialize the values?

Comment: ah yes, sorry for the confusion

Comment: You just defined the variable. So the answer is ... just like you did

Comment: Yes, that is how you define struct as member of struct.Though, those typedefs are redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is how to initialize the array then the answer is like this:

```
Student class_list[2] = {
    {{"John", "Doe"}, {8, "000-555-000"}, {1, 2, 3}},
    {{"Jane", "Doe"}, {10, "000-555-001"}, {10, 8, 10}},
};
```

The reasons it works like this is because your classes are aggregates so you can use [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

Well, I initialized an array of 2 elements. You can see the syntax.

---

Some points for your program. The way of `typedef struct` is a C idiom. In C++ you don't need it so please change all the definitions to:

```
struct Name
{
    char fname[15];
    char lname[15];
};
```

Also you should use `std::array` instead of C arrays:

```
std::array<Student, 3> class_list {{
    {{"John", "Doe"}, {8, "000-555-000"}, {1, 2, 3}},
    {{"Jane", "Doe"}, {10, "000-555-001"}, {10, 8, 10}},
}};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Sorry for the confusion at first.